# Two's company; three's a crowd

Tags: politeness, proverbs

**Two's company; three's a crowd**

I have checked [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Two+is+company,+three%27s+a+crowd)

"(Often implies that you want to be alone with the person because you are romantically interested in him or her.)"

My question: Could you say that to elderly people? Is it polite?

Excuse me, but this question really appears from me as a non-native speaker, thank you.

Comment: It's not polite to say it to anyone. It would be better to say something like, "Would you mind giving X & me some time (to be) alone?" or "We would like some time just to be together."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andy Warhol said, “one's company, two's a crowd, and three's a party.” He is playing with convention here. It is meant to be metaphorical of Andy's social outlook.

To answer your question, it is considered impolite to say "three's a crowd" when in a group of three. You may be telling someone to go away; however, as Andy shows us, it all has to do with social context.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proverb, a saying which expresses a general truth. It is not at all impolite, rude, or obscene when used to express a general truth. However, you make it impolite when you use it as a sort of weapon in conversation, a way of suggesting that someone else is in the way and ought to leave.